# make nested array on the basis of specific array value in php

Tags: php

```
Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 40718
                    [name] => abc1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 40718
                    [name] => abc2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 40719
                    [name] => abc3
                )
    )
```

my array is like having user_id as you can see above i want to convert it into nested array on the basis of specific value from array as user_id like mention below

```
Array
        (
            [40718] => Array
                (
                    [0]=>array(
                        [name] => abc1
                    )

                    [1]=>array(
                        [name] => abc2
                    )
                )

            [40719] => Array
                (
                   [0] => (
                        [name] => abc3
                   )
                )
    )
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Though I haven't tested it, check if it can help you to get your result :

```
<?php

$arrTest = [
    [
        'user_id' => 40718,
        'name' => 'abc1'
    ],
    [
        'user_id' => 40718,
        'name' => 'abc2'
    ],
    [
        'user_id' => 40719,
        'name' => 'abc3'
    ]
];

$resultArr = [];
foreach ($arrTest as $val) {
    $resultArr[$val['user_id']][]['name'] = $val['name'];
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($resultArr); exit;

?>
```